# Writing custom usage statements for a single argument with nargs > 1

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argumentParser that currently outputs a usage statement that looks like this:

```
usage: body arm hand [-h] finger finger finger finger finger
```

Body is the main parser, then arm is a subparser, and hand is a subparser of the subparser. Finger represents an argument that accepts five inputs.

Is there any way to write custom usage statements with the built-in argparse functions for one argument? It should look like:

```
usage: body arm hand [-h] thumb index middle ring pinky
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple metavar should do the job

```
In [270]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='prog')
In [271]: p.add_argument('finger', nargs=5, 
    metavar=('thumb', 'index', 'middle', 'ring', 'pinky'));
In [272]: p.print_usage()
usage: prog [-h] thumb index middle ring pinky
```

It has to be a tuple, not a list, and has to have the same length as `nargs`.  Check `metavar` in the argparse docs.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just realized it was right on the docs. It seems that the tuple doesn't work for me, since it throws 'too many values to unpack'

Comment: What's your `nargs`.  I assumed 5 from the desired display.

Comment: I have three and I'm using a tuple of size three. The line is parser.add_argument('ipmi', nargs=3, metavar=('user','host','pwd')). It might be something specific about the wrapper functions that I'm using, and therefore completely unrelated to this problem. Thanks for pointing out metavar, though!

Comment: If I mismatch `nargs` and metavar I get `ValueError: length of metavar tuple does not match nargs`, not a unpacking error.  `argparse` code doesn't use the `unpacking` syntax very often.  I'd have to see more of the error stack.

Comment: I've looked at the error, and it's the same one you opened a bug issue about two years ago (can't unpack triplet tuples). Seems like it still hasn't been fixed, or I need to update something.

Comment: I was just testing the `usage`.  The problem is in the help line.  And for a positional only. http://bugs.python.org/issue14074.  There's quite a backlog of argparse patches

Comment: Reviewing my patch, this is not a trivial problem.  While the tuple metavar looks nice in the `usage`, a well chosen `dest` is better for `help` and `errors`.  It's all sufficiently complicated that I'm inclined to disallow a tuple metavar for positionals.

Comment: Yep, I agree. My current workaround is to set them as required=True optional flags, which is not the best solution, but since argparse allows required to be changed, it is a solution.